# checked the Check box to start the Service in Android

Tags: android

```
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxSync);
            checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        startService(new Intent(UltilityActivity.this, SynService.class));
                    }
                }
            });
```

this is the check box when checked will start the SynService class.

public class SynService extends Service {

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.d(null,"Create Service");
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service created!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    Log.d(null,"Start Service");
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service started by user.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

and this is the synservice class, but when i have checked, service are not start and nothing happen. why?

second question, when the service are started, i want to sync the data every 30 minutes, where the code i should put in and loop forever until shutdown the device.

Comment: Might need to post more code, do you know if the startService function is being called inside if(isChecked)?

Also for your second question don't use a loop you should use the AlarmManager and just wake your service every 30 minutes.

Comment: @Ben Yes, i know the service are started inside `isChecked`, but still can't start the service when the check box are checked,on second question, i will try the AlarmManager.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand if the service is being started inside isChecked the the service is being started when the check boxes are checked. That onCheckedChanged listener should only be called when the box is checked or unchecked. If you service isn't stopped onStart won't be called the subsequent times. Only onStartCommand will be called.

Comment: @Ben =( , i have no idea to fix this..

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved with add in the AndroidMafifest.xml file with this code

`<service android:name="com.example.abc2.SyncService"

            android:exported="true" android:label="@string/app_name"> 
   <intent-filter><action android:name="com.example.abc2.SyncService"></action>
   </intent-filter>
    </service>`

thanks all